# add span before one of the drop down menu in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have create a drop down menu using html code:

```
[code]

<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a>
    <ul>
    <span class="drop-down-menu-pointer"></span>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" >a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
[/code]
```

I wish to convert it to a wordpress nav menu but I am having problem with creating "span tag" using wordpress menu. Can some body help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress creates menu's that look like this:

```
<ul id="main-menu" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-1234" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-33 current_page_item menu-item-1234">
        <a href="http://www.site.nl/">home</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-1235" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1235">
        <a href="http://www.site.nl/cursussen/">cursussen</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-1244" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1244">
                <a href="http://www.site.nl/cursussen/">cursus overzicht</a>
            </li>
        <li id="menu-item-1237" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1237">
                <a href="http://www.site.nl/maatwerk/">maatwerk</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-1238" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1238">
        <a href="http://www.site.nl/nieuws/">tips en tricks</a>
    </li> 
</ul>
```

There are plenty of classes and structures you can depend on here to do what you want your span to do. For example, with some css like this:

```
ul li ul {
    /*drop-down-menu-pointer styling here, for example, if 
        your main menu has a height of 20 px, this might work*/

    top: -20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    background-image: url('arrowurl.jpg');
    background-position: top right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    /* And you might have to do something with the position attribute */
}
```

It will need some tweaking I guess but it should get you there. Also, look into http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu for all options, maybe something there will help you.

Comment: yes, I know about the styling and I looked into the codex already. But the codex only help to create span for the every attribute of li class or ul class while I only wish to create one and only one span to show an arrow symbolize the belonging of current drop down menu

Comment: I think you can still use the child ul for that. To explain I've extended my answer a bit with some additional css.

Comment: Furthermore, I believe it is impossible to add extra elements to the menu the way you want it to using the normal functions, so in that you are right. You might be able to achieve this by writing a custom menu function in functions.php that uses the returned menu from the standard function and use some regex on it to add the span element, but that's a very slow and ugly technique.